# Swift 3 - Compare two unequal length arrays and append placeholder values in it to make them equal

Tags: ios, arrays, for-loop, swift3, append

My first array is

```
arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4 , 5]
```

My second array is

```
arr2 = [2, 3, 4]
```

I want to compare arr1 against arr2 and output a third array with the output

```
arr3 = ["No match", 2, 3, 4, "No match"]
```

So that I have added a placeholder value at indices where arr1 and arr2 dont match. Arr1 and arr2 will not always be sorted.

How do i go about this in Swift 3? Can't come up with a loop that will work :/

Comment: Is `arr2` always a subarray of `arr1`? arr2 = [2, 4] is possible? arr2 = [4, 2] is possible? What is the result then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a simple solution will be

```
let arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
let arr2 = [2,3,4]

var arr3 = [String]()
for value in arr1{

    if arr2.contains(value){
        arr3.append("\(value)")
    } else {
        arr3.append("No Match")
    }
}
```

one line solution would be

```
let results = arr1.map {arr2.contains($0) ? "\($0)" : "No Match"}
```

Comment: Thanks Akhil, you're a champ. I'm going to pick your brains a bit more. This builds on what we solved here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48562714/swift-3-array-mapping-add-placeholder-values-in-array-based-on-relationship

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
let arr1 = [1,2,7,3,4,5]

let arr2 = [2,3,4,7]

var arr3 = [Any]()
var count = Int()

let sortedArr1 = arr1.sorted()
let sortedArr2 = arr2.sorted()

let arrCount1 = sortedArr1.count
let arrCount2 = sortedArr2.count

if arrCount1 > arrCount2 {
     count = arrCount1
}else {
     count = arrCount2
}

for i in 0..<count {
     if sortedArr2.contains(sortedArr1[i]){
          arr3.append(sortedArr1[i])
     }else {
          arr3.append("Not Matched")
     }
}
```

When you print the output array it will give you the desired result:

```
print(arr3) //Outputs :["Not Matched", 2, 3, 4, "Not Matched", 7]
```

Or the one line code will be like as follows:

```
let arr3 = sortedArr1.map {sortedArr2.contains($0) ? "\($0)" : "Not Matched"}
print(arr3) //Outputs :["Not Matched", 2, 3, 4, "Not Matched", 7]
```

Comment: Thanks all, I have more to this question building on from this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48562714/swift-3-array-mapping-add-placeholder-values-in-array-based-on-relationship

Answer (score 0):

if you want array of string instead of any. you can try this

```
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4 , 5]
let arr2 = [2, 3, 4]

let test = arr1.map{
    (item) -> String in

    if arr2.contains(item){
        return "\(item)"
    }else{
        return "No match"
    }
}
print(test)//["No match", "2", "3", "4", "No match"]
```